# Dijit MenuItem from DropDownMenu.getChildren()

Tags: dojo, menuitem

I created a button (dijit/form/DropDownButton) that when clicked displays a dropdown menu (Dijit/DropDownMenu) of items (dijit/MenuItems). I'm trying to manlipuate the MenuItems after the control is created. I can get the MenuItems from the DropDownMenu by using the getChildren() function; however, can't get the MenuItem object out of the returned array/object.

```
require(["dojo/ready"], function (ready) {
   ready(function () {
      var menu = dijit.byId("drpMenu");
      var menuChildern = menu.getChildren();

    });
 });
```

How do I parse the getChildren() array, to get the individual MenuItems?

Comment: Are you trying to manipulate a specific MenuItem or all of them? What is wrong with doing something like `menuChildren.forEach(function(menuItem){ // Process MenuItems })`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the array using menuChildern[i] or like user Default posted it. If you need to look at the structure of a javascript element do a

```
console.log(menuChildren);
```

with firebug&firefox and keep the console open so you can browse the structure.